# Dart - How to simplify IF conditions using NullAware operators

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there an way to simplify this conditional clause:

```
if (_username != null &&_username.isNotEmpty  && _pass != null && _pass.isNotEmpty){
      connectionBloc.dispatch(GetUserInfoEventImpl(_username, _pass));
    }
```

Using Null-Aware operators?

I tried:

```
if (_username?.isNotEmpty?? false && _pass?.isNotEmpty?? false){
      connectionBloc.dispatch(GetUserInfoEventImpl(_username, _pass));
    }
```

But I think there is a problem because Android Studio says condition on the right cannot be reached, which is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With null-aware access, you must explicitly compare result to true or false:

```
  if (_username?.isNotEmpty == true && _pass?.isNotEmpty == true) {
    ...
  }
```

As for your variant, the code lacks parentheses, because the `Null coalescence operator` has the lowest priority:

```
  if ((_username?.isNotEmpty ?? false) && (_pass?.isNotEmpty ?? false)) {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Personally I would use the second form. `== true` comparisons always feel suspicious, and in the case of potential nulls, the first form takes me longer to reason about.  The `== true` approach for these situations also has the unusual property that it's not equivalent to `!= false`.

Comment: Additionally, in a more general sense, if you're dealing with a possibly null `bool`, `if (someBool == true)` misleadingly looks like it could be simplified to `if (someBool)`, whereas `if (someBool ?? false)` makes it obvious to readers that `someBool` is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
     String test = null;
  bool v = _stringIsNotEmptyOrNull(test);
  print("Boolean value is $v");
  test = "";
  bool v1 = _stringIsNotEmptyOrNull(test);
  print("Boolean value is $v1");
  test = "test";
  bool v2 = _stringIsNotEmptyOrNull(test);
  print("Boolean value is $v2");
```

The checking function can be written as

```
bool _stringIsNotEmptyOrNull(String value) {
return value?.isNotEmpty ?? false;
}
```

or

```
bool _stringIsNotEmptyOrNull(String value) => value?.isNotEmpty ?? false;
```

Comment: for first function names uses naming in cameCase, and function name longer then code inside it - ugly,useless

Comment: @Eugene how do you know that the function is useless, if you know more than me just post an answer